# Crear vista que ejecute una función con parámetros en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas y gracias de antemano a todos, os explico que estoy intentando hacer a ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

He creado una función en SQL Server que me calcula el total de los importes de una tabla a través de un parámetro de entrada

```
CREATE FUNCTION Func_Subtotal(@IdContrato int)
RETURNS DECIMAL (20,5)
AS
-- Devuelve el importe total sumado 
BEGIN
  DECLARE 
    @Unidades decimal(20,10), 
    @Precio   decimal(20,5), 
    @Descuento decimal(20,5),
    @Subtotal decimal(20,5),
    @Precio_con_dto decimal(20,5),
    @retSubtotal decimal(20,5);
-- Get common contact information
DECLARE Cursor_1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
    Unidades, 
    Precio_Euros,
    Descuento
FROM Contratos
WHERE IdContrato = @IdContrato;    

OPEN Cursor_1;

SELECT @Subtotal = 0;
SELECT @retSubtotal = 0;

FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_1
INTO @Unidades, @Precio, @Descuento
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN       
    IF @Descuento = 0
        SELECT @Precio_con_dto = @Precio * 1
    ELSE
        SELECT @Precio_con_dto = @Precio * (@Descuento/100);

    SELECT @Subtotal = @Precio_con_dto * @Unidades;

    IF @IdContrato IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @retSubtotal = @Subtotal + @retSubtotal
    END;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor_1
    INTO @Unidades, @Precio, @Descuento;
END

CLOSE Cursor_1; 

RETURN @retSubtotal;
END;
GO
```

Ahora quiero crear una vista que me saque este "total" junto con el IdCliente de otra tabla llamada Contratos

Lo que no quiero es tener que pasarle a la función un valor fijo sino que el parámetro sea el IdCliente de la tabla Contratos

He probado con la siguiente vista pero me da error

```
create view dbo.pers_subtotal
as 
SELECT a.IdContrato from dbo.Contratos_Lineas a cross  apply
 dbo.Pers_Func_Subtotal (a.IdContrato) b 
where a.IdContrato = b.IdContrato
```

Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Hola Marco. Toma en cuenta que nunca es suficiente simplemente decir que algo te da error. Obviamente, si te pones en nuestro lugar, necesitamos saber qué es ese error.

Comment: `dbo.Func_Subtotal` es una función **escalar**, por lo mismo, no hace sentido usarla en un `CROSS APPLY`; deberías usarla directo en el `SELECT`

Comment: O bien hay que trasformar la función en una de tipo `Table-Valued`, pero viendo un poco el código, no le veo sentido a usar una función, podrías resolverlo con una subconsulta de agregación y evitar los cursores.

Comment: Perfecto.Tiraré por el camino de la subconsulta de agregación. Muchas gracias a todos y perdón por la falta de información en el error, es la primera vez que utilizo esto y estoy un poco perdido. Gracias a todos de nuevo

Answer (score 1):

La función es escalar, por lo tanto no es necesario aplicar CROSS APPLY, basta con llamara la función escalar en un campo... quedaría de la siguiente manera..
create view dbo.pers_subtotal
as 
SELECT IdContrato, dbo.Pers_Func_Subtotal(IdContrato) AS 'TOTAL' from dbo.Contratos_Lineas